# Enable SSI for Lighty2Go

Tags: lighttpd

Lighty2Go is the portable version of the Lighttpd server.  I'm required to use it for a project I am doing.

I need to use SSI (Server Side Includes).  I know SSI is old and slow, that is OK for this project.  I know Lighty2Go/Lighttpd has support for SSI, however, I can't seem to get it to work.

My Index Page:

```
<doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Site</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--#include file="header.txt"-->
        Test Content
    </body>
</html>
```

The header.txt file has this inside:

```
This is header.txt
```

I've changed some settings in the config to no avail.  Any ideas?  Does anybody have a step-by-step way to do it for newbies?  I'm new to Lighty2Go, I'm only using it so I can test my SSI enabled sites before uploading them to a server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the Lighty2Go directory, you'll need to edit the lighttpd config file at `LightTPD/conf/lighttpd-l2g.conf`.

Under `server.modules = (`, uncomment the `"mod_ssi",` line.  Also, uncomment the `ssi.extension = ( ".shtml" )` line near the bottom of the file.